# How to Limit the Playback bar to 10 minutes in vlc player

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, ip-camera

I've been streaming an IP camera using VLC player, and after a few days, the streaming stops. It seems like the playback bar, which stores data for rewind purposes, gets too long and consumes too much of the system's resources, leading to the stream being terminated. I believe that limiting the maximum length of the playback bar to 10 minutes could solve this problem. Is there a way to set a limit on the maximum size of the playback bar to 10 minutes in the settings?